# Writing and reading strange letters to a txt-file using libcurl

Tags: html, c++, unicode, libcurl

I have a c++ program that downloads the HTML-code of a webpage and saves it as a  text file using the library LibCurl. The problem is, that we have the following strange letters in danish alphabet: Æ æ Ø ø Å å.
When I try to read the HTML-code line by line, all these characters look like "�". I have tried to read/write the file as wide characters. That did not work.
I have also tried to write a sentence containing "æ", "ø" og "å" to another text file and read it again. That, for some reason, worked.

So my question is, why does the strange letters look like "�" when they are in the downloaded HTML-code but not when I write my own sentence? And how do I fix the HTML-output?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include<curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;


static size_t write_data (string * ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,void *stream)
{
 size_t written = fwrite (ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *) stream);
  cout << static_cast <const void *> (ptr);
  return written;
  //string myString (ptr, nbytes);
}
//string myString (ptr, nbytes);
int main ()
{
// Writing weird characters to a text-file!
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Print strange letter: æ ø og å!";
myfile.close ();

// Reading weird characters from the text-file!
std::ifstream wif ("example.txt");
if (wif.is_open ())
{
  std::string wline;
  while (std::getline (wif, wline))
{
  cout << wline << endl;

}
}
else
cout << "Could not open file" << endl ;
wif.close ();

cout << endl << endl;


// Download the HTML-code from a webpage and save it.
CURL *curl_handle;
static const char *pagefilename = "example2.txt";
const char *charUrl = "http://politiken.dk/forbrugogliv/sundhedogmotion/ECE3406716/mindst-85000-offentligt-ansatte-maa-slet-ikke-ryge-i-arbejdstiden/"; // An article from the danish newspaper "Politiken"

FILE *pagefile;
curl_global_init (CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
curl_handle = curl_easy_init ();
curl_easy_setopt (curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, charUrl);   // HERE IS THE URL PASSED!
curl_easy_setopt (curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt (curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
curl_easy_setopt (curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
pagefile = fopen (pagefilename, "wb");

if (pagefile)
{
  curl_easy_setopt (curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pagefile);
  curl_easy_perform (curl_handle);
  fclose (pagefile);
}
curl_easy_cleanup (curl_handle);

//Reading the HTML-code
ifstream webIn ("example2.txt");
if (webIn.is_open ())
{
  std::string wline;
  while (getline (webIn, wline))
{
  cout << wline << endl;
}
}
else
cout << "Could not open example.txt" << endl;



return 0;
}
```

And my output is

```
Print strange letter: æ ø og å!


>>HTML-CODE CONTAINING "�" instead of æ ø å <<
```

I don't know if it is relevant, but my OS is Linux Mint 17.3 and I've set the language and region og my system to "English, Denmark UTF-8".

Thanks in advance! I will really appreciate any help or hints :)

Comment: Looks to me like you forgot to set your application's locale. By default, applications run in the C locale, with the US-ASCII character set, and that's the locate the wide streams will use by default. Try setting `std::locale::global()` before opening your wide character streams, or explicitly imbue the locale into the wide stream.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If the OP handles input using `char` to represent an octet then surely there wouldn't be any information-loss? Isn't the problem just that his terminal program doesn't support UTF-8?

Comment: @Dal - the code is writing `char` data into a file, and reads it back with a wide character file stream. The wide character file stream's locale's character set must match whatever character set is used for the original characters.

Comment: But  if setting the locale before opening the wide character stream would help, why does the code written above work for example.txt but not for example2.txt?